# Nightmare not returning correct value from evaluate

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

I am using Nightmare in javascript to create a web scraper, but the evaluate function is not returning the correct information. It seems that it is capable of returning primitive types (ints, strings, etc) but not a list of elements from "querySelectorAll". The following code works just fine:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare'); // make a new nightmare
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true }); // display it (change to false for text only)





nightmare
.goto('http://stackoverflow.com/questions') // go to stack overflow

.evaluate(function () {
    var all_options = document.querySelectorAll(".summarycount");
    return all_options[0].innerHTML;

})
// .end()
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
});
```

And prints out "13,844,183" or whatever the current number of questions asked is. However when I try to return all of the options from the evaluate function, changing the evaluate and then functions like so:

```
.evaluate(function () {
    var all_options = document.querySelectorAll(".summarycount");
    return all_options;

})
// .end()
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result[0].innerHTML);
})
```

It just prints undefined. So the value returned by the evaluate function is not the proper list of all matching DOM elements. Is there any way around this? Ideally the script will be capable of finding multiple elements from a list, selecting each one, then run more code (possibly involving selecting more options) on the page then evaluating the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that evaluate must return a primitive type. I fixed part of my problem by just handling all of the clicking and processing of the data inside the evaluate function.